# Django Admin database Query or Models error: DoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: database, django, django-models, admin

I am getting a database Query:  DoesNotExist at /admin/  even those I know that data I am querying is in database.  I could be Models error.
Ok I can't give the code but here is example layout in my models

```
Deliver(model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
 def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

Item(model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

ItemVersion(model):
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
  version = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.item + "-" + self.version

ItemAndDeliver(model):
 itemVer = models.ForeignKey(ItemVersion)
 deliver = models.ForeignKey(Deliver)

 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.itemVer + "-" + self.deliver
```

I am getting error Item DoesNotExist even though it is in database, it points to

```
ItemVersion= def __unicode__(self):
      return self.item + "-" + self.version
```

as the cause but I am able to go the ItemVersion selection of admin area to select item version and will query the database no problem. The problem seems to be with ItemAndDeliver model as rest work fine as far as I can see.

I can't figure out why it is not working and can't find any information on what would be the cause. It was work before but not now.

Comment: You probably have some inconsistent data in the database. Example: You have deleted `Item` or `Deliver` object and the reference exists in the database for some reason in the `ItemAndDeliver` or `ItemAndDeliver` models

Comment: Everything is still in database as it's displaying on the web front end for ItemAndDeliver and I can view ItemVersion and Item in the admin site. It's only when I try to edit a ItemAndDeliver entry using the admin site I get the error.